# How to fill shirt patterns into a shirt silhouette with realistic form "twist"?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, patterns, batch-processing, automation

I currently have xxx amount of patterns that I want to apply to a shirt silhouette. My challenge is that I naturally want to apply the pattern with realistic "twist" and form on arms, collar etc.

So far ive been looking at Photoshop and the actions auto batch processor, but im wondering if this can be automated and done at all here. Or in any case, which other software I could use for this.

My thought is to:
- Split up the shirt in different sections, like : left arm, right arm, body etc.
- Fill the pattern in each section
- Do individual section "twist" forming the pattern in "correct" realistic direction.

To very roughly outline what im looking to do, ive put together a small gif that can be seen here:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/sELU7rP.gif]

Any suggestions?

Comment: My first thought is that it would be best to do this in some flavor of 3D modeling software, you could then presumably create a UV map and batch create and apply different patterns to the map. If you're not already comfortable with 3D modeling, this would likely be a daunting task for a beginner

Answer (score 3):

It can be done by using pattern in photoshop by

1. first of all  define a pattern for that you

   edit->define pattern
2. right click on your layer and then select blending option and than
3. go to pattern option and select your recently saved pattern (probably that would be last one)

now you will have that pattern on you image

Answer (score 1):

I would do this in four ways.

1. Create a smart object three times.  That would leave each sleeve and the chest.  You would only have to create your sleeves and chest once but you could apply the patterns easily through a batch sequence.
2. As already stated use a 3D modeling program.  Blender is a great opensource and has a powerful community of backers.
3. You would have to pay but I beleive the autodesk version is called MudBox that works on skins and effects for 3D modeling.  I'll have to verify the third one but I know an Autodesk product would help.
4. If you don't need to use this image exactly and are just wanting a shirt there are some smart objects pre made by [Gomedia](http://arsenal.gomedia.us/templates.html) that you can buy.

Comment: zbrush is another popular alternative to Mudbox. They're both 3D programs with a focus on 'sculpting', and popular with designers as they're a bit more intuitive and craft-like to use than blender which I gather is much more focussed on technical commands.